# Installers are not working anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

Recently I re-installed my Windows 7 Home 32 bit.
At a moment I realized that almost no installer is working. 
For example this installer from Microsoft web site: http://content.systemrequirementslab.com/global/bin/intel_srldetect_4.5.13.0.msi
When I start it is shows its interface for about 0.5 seconds then it disappear. No error messages. Nothing.

Same behavior for dotNetFx35setup.exe (but for this, there are no messages in Event Viewer).

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

I get these messages in EVENT VIEWER:

1. Beginning a Windows Installer transaction: G:\KIT\DRIVERI\Toshiba
   Qosmio X505 Q860\Chipset\Intel driver update utility.msi. Client
   Process Id: 3224.
2. Starting session 0 - ‎2013‎-‎07‎-‎12T18:09:53.945993900Z.
3. Ending a Windows Installer transaction: G:\KIT\DRIVERI\Toshiba
   Qosmio X505 Q860\Chipset\Intel driver update utility.msi. Client
   Process Id: 3224.
4. Product: System Requirements Lab for Intel -- Configuration completed successfully.
5. Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: System Requirements Lab for Intel. Product Version: 4.5.13.0. Product
   Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Husdawg, LLC. Reconfiguration success
   or error status: 0.
6. Ending session 0 started ‎2013‎-‎07‎-‎12T18:09:53.945993900Z.

---

I downloaded MS installer from MS web site (Windows6.0 installer-KB942288-v2-x86). It is not working also. It says: "Windows Update Standalone Installer-The update is not applicable to your computer." But this is the 32 bit installer for Win 7 and I DO have win 7 32 bits.

Comment: Did you check the event viewer for errors? Also, make sure the installer service is not disabled. Start->Run, type services.msc. look for "Windows Installer". Make sure the Startup type is Manual and you can try starting it.

Comment: @xxl3ww - yes, it is set to manual and it says 'started'.

Comment: I believe Windows6.0 installer-KB942288-v2-x86 is for Vista and previous versions of Windows. If you run "msiexec -" from a command prompt it will show what version you're running. I'm running 5.0.7601.17514 right now and I'm on Windows 7 Pro

Comment: test a 7zip installer http://www.7-zip.org/download.html. I don't think anything is wrong with your Windows Installer